# How to wait for async data before send response using promises and arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, arrow-functions

I'm new to ES6, arrow functions and promises, and I can't figure out how to use them, even worse together.

I started a project with a REST generator (https://github.com/diegohaz/rest) and it works fine, but I need to modify part of the authentication.

I need to return data from a third-party server during authentication. I created the function that returns the data correctly with axios, however I can't return this information along with the other information (from this project), response is sent before.

Below is the generated code, almost untouchable, I added just `extraData: user.getExtraData(user)`

```
// function in auth controller file
export const login = ({ user }, res, next) => {
  sign(user.id)
    .then((token) => ({
      token, user: user.view(true), extraData: user.getExtraData(user)
    }))
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch(next)
}

// function in user model file
view (full) {
    let view = {}
    let fields = ['id', 'name', 'picture']
    if (full) {
      fields = [...fields, 'email', 'createdAt']
    }
    fields.forEach((field) => { 
      view[field] = this[field] 
    })     
    return view
}
```

Here is my function added into the user model

```
getExtraData (userView) {
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    axios.post( userView.host, querystring.stringify( {
      data1:userView.data1,
      data2:userView.data2
    }))
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error', error)
        return null        
      })
}
```

How would the best way to make response wait until extraData is return from getExtraData function with the given code ? Thanks

Comment: `getExtraData` doesn't return anything - and the only useful thing it could return is a promise ... so `extraData:` would be a promise, not a value

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yes... but then how to assign response.data to extraData?

Comment: asynchronously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **async/await**. In that case, you need to `await` for `getExtraData`. For such reason, the anonymous function inside `login` and `getExtraData` both need to be declared as asynchronous functions:

```
// function in auth controller file
export const login = ({ user }, res, next) => {
    sign(user.id)
    .then(async (token) => ({
        token, 
        user: user.view(true), 
        // Wait for getExtraData to finish using await
        extraData: await user.getExtraData(user)
    }))
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch(next)
}

async getExtraData (userView) {
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    try {
        const response = await axios.post( userView.host, querystring.stringify( {
            data1:userView.data1,
            data2:userView.data2
        }))

        return response.data
    }
    catch (err){
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel let me know if this works for you. Otherwise, tell me what went wrong

Comment: Hi, I'm getting error on await user.getExtraData(user). SyntaxError: auth/controller.js: await is a reserved word

Comment: Hey.... You helped me a lot and it's working now. I needed to fix one little thing. I had to put async in `.then(async (token) => ({` instead of `export const login = async ({`  Thanks

Comment: Oh, God! You were right Daniel. In fact I never noticed the call to `getExtraData` was inside another function. Thanks for pointing that out and editing my answer. I had to help you on the fly because I had no way of checking the code. If you think the answer is correct now, please, mark it as **accepted** (green checkmark). That could help other people with your same issue. Thanks in advance!